# Pyinstaller - ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes27.dll)

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller

I am trying to package my python script into an executable. I thought I would be pretty straight forward as I don't have very many imports. First off here are my imports:

```
from __future__ import print_function 
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import os
from progressbar import Percentage,Bar,ETA,ProgressBar,RotatingMarker
```

I know for a fact that `numpy` is supported I'm not sure about `__future__` or `os` and I know for sure that `netCDF4` and `progressbar` are not supported. I am using pyinstaller version 2.1 on Python 2.7.7 for Windows 7, and here is the command I use to start creating .exe:

```
C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\netcdf_grid_extraction>pyinstaller --onefile --hidden-i
mport=netCDF4 --hidden-import=progressbar netcdf_grid_extraction.py
```

Here is a list of errors. There seems to be one major problem with not being able to find the module `pywintypes.dll`, as well as two assemblies related to `amd64_Microsoft`. Here is a list of the 4 errors I get. How can I go about solving these?

## 1

```
1130 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.
21022.8_none ...
1134 WARNING: Assembly not found
1134 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none
not found
1210 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.
21022.8_none ...
1210 WARNING: Assembly not found
1210 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none
not found
```

## 2

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <m
odule>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", li
ne 124, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", li
ne 98, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    raise ImportError("No system module '%s' (%s)" % (modname, filename))
ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes27.dll)
4155 INFO: Processing hook hook-pywintypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <m
odule>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", li
ne 124, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", li
ne 98, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    raise ImportError("No system module '%s' (%s)" % (modname, filename))
ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes27.dll)
```

## 3

```
5840 INFO: Searching for assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.
21022.8_none ...
5840 WARNING: Assembly not found
5840 ERROR: Assembly amd64_Microsoft.VC90.CRT_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none
not found
```

## 4

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 9, in <mo
dule>
    load_entry_point('PyInstaller==2.1', 'console_scripts', 'pyinstaller')()
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\Py
Installer\main.py", line 88, in run
    run_build(opts, spec_file, pyi_config)
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\Py
Installer\main.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.build.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **opts.__dict__)
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\Py
Installer\build.py", line 1924, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'
))
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\Py
Installer\build.py", line 1873, in build
    execfile(spec)
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Desktop\netcdf_grid_extraction\netcdf_grid_extraction.s
pec", line 17, in <module>
    console=True )
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\Py
Installer\build.py", line 1170, in __init__
    strip_binaries=self.strip, upx_binaries=self.upx,
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\Py
Installer\build.py", line 1008, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\Py
Installer\build.py", line 309, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\Py
Installer\build.py", line 1050, in assemble
    dist_nm=inm)
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\Py
Installer\build.py", line 842, in checkCache
    digest = cacheDigest(fnm)
  File "C:\Users\Patrick\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-2.1-py2.7.egg\Py
Installer\build.py", line 796, in cacheDigest
    data = open(fnm, "rb").read()
IOError: [Errno 22] invalid mode ('rb') or filename: ''
```

And here are the warnings I get that may or may not be relevent and are both related to not being able to find `ctypes`

```
890 WARNING: library python%s%s required via ctypes not found
2175 WARNING: library python%s%s required via ctypes not found
```

The good news is that its seems the third party modules are being accounted for however I am not sure if they are associated with the errors that I am gettting:

```
4540 INFO: Hidden import 'netCDF4' has been found otherwise
4540 INFO: Hidden import 'progressbar' has been found otherwise
4540 INFO: Hidden import 'codecs' has been found otherwise
4545 INFO: Hidden import 'encodings' has been found otherwise
```

Comment: what happens if you do `C:\path\to\pyinstaller.py --onefile netcdf_grid_extraction.py`?

Comment: I get the exact same errors 1 to 4 mentioned above with the same warnings except there are no lines saying `4540 INFO: Hidden import 'netCDF4' has been found otherwise` or `4540 INFO: Hidden import 'progressbar' has been found otherwise` as it did before. I should also mention I am using the python included in Anaconda (which is my default python appended to my path)

Comment: Weirdest thing is I installed pyinstaller the same way as my work computer and tried this same command at home (on the same OS and version of python also installed with Anaconda and I have a .exe now) mind you there is now issues importing `netCDF4` when the executable is run but its a start. Not sure how to explain the cause of these differences...

Answer (score 11):

I just copied the DLL `pywintypes27.dll` in `C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32`.
I added it in `win32/lib`.

It's OK!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. The dll, pywintypes27.dll was in C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pywin32_system32.  I added this directory to my PATH environment variable and py2exe was able to find the DLL. Obviously, setting the path is not the correct solution (and you could possibly do it programatically via os.environ), but, works for me.

Answer (score 6):

Solution to prob 2. The solution in the link below solved the issue for me :)

With pywin32 build 219 installed via conda on python 2.7, importing pythoncom fails with

```
ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes27.dll)
```

The issue is that the library pywintypes27.dll is stored not in

```
pathtovenv\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes27.dll
```

but in

```
pathtovenv\lib\site-packages\win32\pywintypes27.dll
```

Adding in the file win32\lib\pywintypes.py the elif part here below solves the issue

```
if found is None:
    # Not in the Python directory?  Maybe we were installed via
    # easy_install...
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), filename)):
        found = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), filename)
    elif os.path.isfile(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", filename)):
        found = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "..", filename)
```

In short terms it looks like pywintypes27.dll is located in the wrong folder

http://sourceforge.net/p/pywin32/bugs/685/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Copied the answer in the link.

Answer (score 4):

I was using a virtual env and had the same problem. The pywintypes35.dll was missing. This was my solution:

```
pip install pypiwin32
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
import win32api
```

I also faced this module not found error multiple times when I recently came to know that win32api should be called in order to get rid of this problem. Do tell if this solution works for you

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're still looking for help on this.

Errors **1** and **3** look like the same error.  [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27911011/create-exe-with-pyinstaller-error-assembly-amd64-microsoft-vc90-crt-1fc8b3b9a1) pointed me in the right direction.  Essentially, install the [MS VC++ 9.0 x64 redistribution package](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336), and that should take care of those errors.

Error **2** appears to have been taken care of by following Lee's suggestion.

Error **4** is because, for some reason, PyInstaller stuck some empty file names in your binary list. I'm not sure if there's a less-hacky way to fix the error, but I was able to get around it by putting

```
for b in a.binaries:
    if b[0] == '':
        a.binaries.remove(b)
```

after the `Analysis( ... )` block in my spec file.

I'm not sure if the `library python%s%s required via ctypes not found` warnings are relevant. They're awfully suspicious, but I went down a rabbit hole trying to figure out where those warnings were generated and only succeeded in wasting about two hours of my evening.

Answer (score 0):

You should run post-install script for the pywin32 extensions with a '-install' parameter, to ensure the environment is setup correctly.

`pywin32_postinstall.py -install`

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\install\pywin32_postinstall.py", line 605, in <module>
    install()
  File ".\install\pywin32_postinstall.py", line 328, in install
    LoadSystemModule(lib_dir, "pywintypes")
  File ".\install\pywin32_postinstall.py", line 166, in LoadSystemModule
    mod = imp.load_dynamic(modname, filename)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

My mistake was that I installed pywin32 via pip **for user**

```
pip install pywin32 --user
```

So the needed DLLs were in user's AppData: %appdata%\Python\Python27\site-packages
That's why pywin32_postinstall.py couldn't find them.

Re-installing without --user option helped.

Answer (score 0):

Fix: No system module pywintypes (pywintypes39.dll).

The first step is to open the Python installation directory and find the "pywin32_system32" folder

[image: images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERVu5.png]

The second step is to copy the entire folder to "project name\venv\Lib\site-packages"

[image: images: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P8JY0.png]

Sources:https://programmersought.com/article/92924476575/

Good Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

I am using **python version 3.8** so I am copying files which ends with 38  (e.g. `xyz38.dll`)

1. Download from internet and Copy `pythoncom38.dll`  and  `pywintype38.dll` in the location:

   C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\win32

> NOTE: This location may vary pc to pc so go to that location which is
> there in the error displayed in `module pywintypes` or `py_xyz not found` error.

(also paste both .dll files in libs or Lib or lib folder inside all win32 folder available at that location)

2. **Close** the python application and **Re-launch** and run your program again **[works 100%]**
3. If above doesn't work then uninstall pypiwin32 in command prompt
   `pip uninstall pypiwin32` and then `pip install pipiwin32`
   and repeat 1st and 2nd step and **Restart** your pc