# ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes34.dll)

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am a Python newbie, trying to package a python script as an exe.

I installed pywin32 from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20218/) and downloaded pyinstaller from [here](http://www.pyinstaller.org/).

I've kinda been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=96jjXwQrznE) video and when I try to package my file as at [4:21](https://youtu.be/96jjXwQrznE?t=261), I get the following error:

```
F:\Softs\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller-3.2.1>python pyinstaller.py test.py --onefile
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyinstaller.py", line 14, in <module>
    from PyInstaller.__main__ import run
  File "F:\Softs\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import PyInstaller.building.build_main
  File "F:\Softs\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 32, in <module>
    from ..depend import bindepend
  File "F:\Softs\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\depend\bindepend.py", line 38, in <module>
    from ..utils.win32.winmanifest import RT_MANIFEST
  File "F:\Softs\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winmanifest.py", line 97, in <module>
    from PyInstaller.utils.win32 import winresource
  File "F:\Softs\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller-3.2.1\PyInstaller\utils\win32\winresource.py", line 20, in <module>
    import pywintypes
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 124, in <module>
    __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 98, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
    raise ImportError("No system module '%s' (%s)" % (modname, filename))
ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes34.dll)
```

I looked up the error and I can only find solutions for -

```
ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes27.dll)
```

which didn't work for me. Could somebody suggest where I am going wrong? A hint would be good.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254285/pyinstaller-importerror-no-system-module-pywintypes-pywintypes27-dll

Comment: Ah, didn't see that one. Thanks a ton brother.

Comment: Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

The `pywintypes38.dll` file is actually installed in the folder path:

```
C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pywin32_system32
```

[image: The files present at the path]

**I copied these files from here to this new path:**

```
C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\win32\lib
```

and, it worked fine for me.