# I am making a virtual assisstant and i get an error - ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes39.dll)

Tags: python, pyttsx3

I am making a Virtual Assistant and I am using the module pyttsx3 with sapi5.

My code -

```
         engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
         voices = engine.getProperty('voices')

         engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)
```

It gives an error  -

```
            Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 20, in init
            eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
        File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\weakref.py", line 134, in __getitem__
            o = self.data[key]()
        KeyError: 'sapi5'

        During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

        Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "d:\Python projects\JARVIS\Jarvis.py", line 18, in <module>
            engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\__init__.py", line 22, in init
            eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in __init__
            self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 50, in __init__
            self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
        File "C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
        File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 10, in <module>
            import pythoncom
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\pythoncom.py", line 2, in <module>
            import pywintypes
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 105, in <module>
            __import_pywin32_system_module__("pywintypes", globals())
        File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\win32\lib\pywintypes.py", line 87, in __import_pywin32_system_module__
            raise ImportError("No system module '%s' (%s)" % (modname, filename))
        ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes39.dll)
```

Can someone help me please? Also I am using Windows 10, Python 3 and the module pyttsx3.

Thanks In Advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254285/pyinstaller-importerror-no-system-module-pywintypes-pywintypes27-dll

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyinstaller - ImportError: No system module 'pywintypes' (pywintypes27.dll)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25254285/pyinstaller-importerror-no-system-module-pywintypes-pywintypes27-dll)

Comment: @Ajay No i had already tried that, i did not solve my problem. Just for that , i tried to reinstall Python but that too did not do anything!